# Cancel lodash's debounce, without invoking the function

Tags: javascript, lodash

My question is, if there is a way to cancel lodash's debounce, without invoking the function to debounce.
The `.cancel()` from lodash still invokes the function.

Maybe I am looking for the wrong approach. If so, is there any other solution for something like this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling the `cancel` method on the debounced function does not invoke it, *unless* it is on the trailing edge of the timeout. You can use the `trailing` option to configure this. [Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

```js
const fn1 = () => console.log('Called 1');
const fn2 = () => console.log('Called 2');
const fn3 = () => console.log('Called 3');

const debouncedFn1 = _.debounce(fn1, 1000);
const debouncedFn2 = _.debounce(fn2, 1000);
const debouncedFn3 = _.debounce(fn3, 1000, { trailing: false });

// Will not log
debouncedFn1();
setTimeout(debouncedFn1.cancel, 200);

// Will log
debouncedFn2();
setTimeout(debouncedFn2.cancel, 1000);

// Will not log
debouncedFn3();
setTimeout(debouncedFn3.cancel, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I don't really understand, why fn1 is never called. Also is it correct that setting trailing: false as only option, will never invoke it?

Comment: @philman fn1 is never called because it is cancelled way before the timer expires. Based on the docs setting the trailing to false will never invoke it if the timer expires as you cancel it.